# Print the data in ResultSet along with column names

Tags: java, mysql, scala, jdbc

I am retrieving columns names from a SQL database through Java. I know I can retrieve columns names from `ResultSet` too. So I have this sql query

```
 select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='suppliers'
```

The problem is I don't know how can I get columns names from `ResultSet` and my code is

```
public void getAllColumnNames() throws Exception{

String sql = "SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='suppliers'";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
 // extract values from rs


}
```

Comment: printing the resultset in java and scala using jdbc is pretty much same. added scala tag for scala users

Answer (score 127):

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from foo");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
        String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);
        System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**Reference :** [Printing the result of ResultSet](https://coderwall.com/p/609ppa/printing-the-result-of-resultset)

Answer (score 17):

1) Instead of `PreparedStatement` use `Statement`

2) After executing query in `ResultSet`, extract values with the help of `rs.getString()` as :

```
Statement st=cn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
    rs.getString(1); //or rs.getString("column name");
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know the column name, how can s/he use `rs.getString("column name");`?

Answer (score 4):

use further as

```
rs.getString(1);
rs.getInt(2);
```

1, 2 is the column number of table and set int or string as per data-type of coloumn

Answer (score 2):

For those who wanted more better version of the resultset printing as util class
This was really helpful for printing resultset and does many things from a single [util](https://github.com/htorun/dbtableprinter)... thanks to Hami Torun!

In this class `printResultSet` uses `ResultSetMetaData` in a generic way have a look at it..

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public final class DBTablePrinter {

    /**
     * Column type category for CHAR, VARCHAR
     * and similar text columns.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_STRING = 1;
    /**
     * Column type category for TINYINT, SMALLINT,
     * INT and BIGINT columns.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_INTEGER = 2;
    /**
     * Column type category for REAL, DOUBLE,
     * and DECIMAL columns.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_DOUBLE = 3;
    /**
     * Column type category for date and time related columns like
     * DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP etc.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_DATETIME = 4;
    /**
     * Column type category for BOOLEAN columns.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_BOOLEAN = 5;
    /**
     * Column type category for types for which the type name
     * will be printed instead of the content, like BLOB,
     * BINARY, ARRAY etc.
     */
    public static final int CATEGORY_OTHER = 0;
    /**
     * Default maximum number of rows to query and print.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_ROWS = 10;
    /**
     * Default maximum width for text columns
     * (like a VARCHAR) column.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH = 150;

    /**
     * Overloaded method that prints rows from table tableName
     * to standard out using the given database connection
     * conn. Total number of rows will be limited to
     * {@link #DEFAULT_MAX_ROWS} and
     * {@link #DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH} will be used to limit
     * the width of text columns (like a VARCHAR column).
     *
     * @param conn      Database connection object (java.sql.Connection)
     * @param tableName Name of the database table
     */
    public static void printTable(Connection conn, String tableName) {
        printTable(conn, tableName, DEFAULT_MAX_ROWS, DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH);
    }

    /**
     * Overloaded method that prints rows from table tableName
     * to standard out using the given database connection
     * conn. Total number of rows will be limited to
     * maxRows and
     * {@link #DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH} will be used to limit
     * the width of text columns (like a VARCHAR column).
     *
     * @param conn      Database connection object (java.sql.Connection)
     * @param tableName Name of the database table
     * @param maxRows   Number of max. rows to query and print
     */
    public static void printTable(Connection conn, String tableName, int maxRows) {
        printTable(conn, tableName, maxRows, DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH);
    }

    /**
     * Overloaded method that prints rows from table tableName
     * to standard out using the given database connection
     * conn. Total number of rows will be limited to
     * maxRows and
     * maxStringColWidth will be used to limit
     * the width of text columns (like a VARCHAR column).
     *
     * @param conn              Database connection object (java.sql.Connection)
     * @param tableName         Name of the database table
     * @param maxRows           Number of max. rows to query and print
     * @param maxStringColWidth Max. width of text columns
     */
    public static void printTable(Connection conn, String tableName, int maxRows, int maxStringColWidth) {
        if (conn == null) {
            System.err.println("DBTablePrinter Error: No connection to database (Connection is null)!");
            return;
        }
        if (tableName == null) {
            System.err.println("DBTablePrinter Error: No table name (tableName is null)!");
            return;
        }
        if (tableName.length() == 0) {
            System.err.println("DBTablePrinter Error: Empty table name!");
            return;
        }
        if (maxRows 
     * ResultSet to standard out using {@link #DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH}
     * to limit the width of text columns.
     *
     * @param rs The ResultSet to print
     */
    public static void printResultSet(ResultSet rs) {
        printResultSet(rs, DEFAULT_MAX_TEXT_COL_WIDTH);
    }

    /**
     * Overloaded method to print rows of a 
     * ResultSet to standard out using maxStringColWidth
     * to limit the width of text columns.
     *
     * @param rs                The ResultSet to print
     * @param maxStringColWidth Max. width of text columns
     */
    public static void printResultSet(ResultSet rs, int maxStringColWidth) {
        try {
            if (rs == null) {
                System.err.println("DBTablePrinter Error: Result set is null!");
                return;
            }
            if (rs.isClosed()) {
                System.err.println("DBTablePrinter Error: Result Set is closed!");
                return;
            }
            if (maxStringColWidth  columns = new ArrayList(columnCount);

            // List of table names. Can be more than one if it is a joined
            // table query
            List tableNames = new ArrayList(columnCount);

            // Get the columns and their meta data.
            // NOTE: columnIndex for rsmd.getXXX methods STARTS AT 1 NOT 0
            for (int i = 1; i  maxStringColWidth) {
                                value = value.substring(0, maxStringColWidth - 3) + "...";
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    // Adjust the column width
                    c.setWidth(value.length() > c.getWidth() ? value.length() : c.getWidth());
                    c.addValue(value);
                } // END of for loop columnCount
                rowCount++;

            } // END of while (rs.next)

            /*
            At this point we have gone through meta data, get the
            columns and created all Column objects, iterated over the
            ResultSet rows, populated the column values and adjusted
            the column widths.
            We cannot start printing just yet because we have to prepare
            a row separator String.
             */

            // For the fun of it, I will use StringBuilder
            StringBuilder strToPrint = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder rowSeparator = new StringBuilder();

            /*
            Prepare column labels to print as well as the row separator.
            It should look something like this:
            +--------+------------+------------+-----------+  (row separator)
            | EMP_NO | BIRTH_DATE | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |  (labels row)
            +--------+------------+------------+-----------+  (row separator)
             */

            // Iterate over columns
            for (Column c : columns) {
                int width = c.getWidth();

                // Center the column label
                String toPrint;
                String name = c.getLabel();
                int diff = width - name.length();

                if ((diff % 2) == 1) {
                    // diff is not divisible by 2, add 1 to width (and diff)
                    // so that we can have equal padding to the left and right
                    // of the column label.
                    width++;
                    diff++;
                    c.setWidth(width);
                }

                int paddingSize = diff / 2; // InteliJ says casting to int is redundant.

                // Cool String repeater code thanks to user102008 at stackoverflow.com

                String padding = new String(new char[paddingSize]).replace("\0", " ");

                toPrint = "| " + padding + name + padding + " ";
                // END centering the column label

                strToPrint.append(toPrint);

                rowSeparator.append("+");
                rowSeparator.append(new String(new char[width + 2]).replace("\0", "-"));
            }

            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            // Is this really necessary ??
            lineSeparator = lineSeparator == null ? "\n" : lineSeparator;

            rowSeparator.append("+").append(lineSeparator);

            strToPrint.append("|").append(lineSeparator);
            strToPrint.insert(0, rowSeparator);
            strToPrint.append(rowSeparator);

            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
            for (String name : tableNames) {
                sj.add(name);
            }

            String info = "Printing " + rowCount;
            info += rowCount > 1 ? " rows from " : " row from ";
            info += tableNames.size() > 1 ? "tables " : "table ";
            info += sj.toString();

            System.out.println(info);

            // Print out the formatted column labels
            System.out.print(strToPrint.toString());

            String format;

            // Print out the rows
            for (int i = 0; i 
     * Integers should not be truncated so column widths should
     * be adjusted without a column width limit. Text columns should be
     * left justified and can be truncated to a max. column width etc...
     * 
     * See also: 
     * java.sql.Types
     *
     * @param type Generic SQL type
     * @return The category this type belongs to
     */
    private static int whichCategory(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case Types.BIGINT:
            case Types.TINYINT:
            case Types.SMALLINT:
            case Types.INTEGER:
                return CATEGORY_INTEGER;

            case Types.REAL:
            case Types.DOUBLE:
            case Types.DECIMAL:
                return CATEGORY_DOUBLE;

            case Types.DATE:
            case Types.TIME:
            case Types.TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE:
            case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
                return CATEGORY_DATETIME;

            case Types.BOOLEAN:
                return CATEGORY_BOOLEAN;

            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.NVARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
            case Types.CHAR:
            case Types.NCHAR:
                return CATEGORY_STRING;

            default:
                return CATEGORY_OTHER;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Represents a database table column.
     */
    private static class Column {

        /**
         * Column label.
         */
        private String label;

        /**
         * Generic SQL type of the column as defined in
         * 
         * java.sql.Types
         * .
         */
        private int type;

        /**
         * Generic SQL type name of the column as defined in
         * 
         * java.sql.Types
         * .
         */
        private String typeName;

        /**
         * Width of the column that will be adjusted according to column label
         * and values to be printed.
         */
        private int width = 0;

        /**
         * Column values from each row of a ResultSet.
         */
        private List values = new ArrayList();

        /**
         * Flag for text justification using String.format.
         * Empty string ("") to justify right,
         * dash (-) to justify left.
         *
         * @see #justifyLeft()
         */
        private String justifyFlag = "";

        /**
         * Column type category. The columns will be categorised according
         * to their column types and specific needs to print them correctly.
         */
        private int typeCategory = 0;

        /**
         * Constructs a new Column with a column label,
         * generic SQL type and type name (as defined in
         * 
         * java.sql.Types
         * )
         *
         * @param label    Column label or name
         * @param type     Generic SQL type
         * @param typeName Generic SQL type name
         */
        public Column(String label, int type, String typeName) {
            this.label = label;
            this.type = type;
            this.typeName = typeName;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the column label
         *
         * @return Column label
         */
        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the generic SQL type of the column
         *
         * @return Generic SQL type
         */
        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the generic SQL type name of the column
         *
         * @return Generic SQL type name
         */
        public String getTypeName() {
            return typeName;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the width of the column
         *
         * @return Column width
         */
        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the width of the column to width
         *
         * @param width Width of the column
         */
        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        /**
         * Adds a String representation (value)
         * of a value to this column object's {@link #values} list.
         * These values will come from each row of a
         * 
         * ResultSet
         *  of a database query.
         *
         * @param value The column value to add to {@link #values}
         */
        public void addValue(String value) {
            values.add(value);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the column value at row index i.
         * Note that the index starts at 0 so that getValue(0)
         * will get the value for this column from the first row
         * of a 
         * ResultSet.
         *
         * @param i The index of the column value to get
         * @return The String representation of the value
         */
        public String getValue(int i) {
            return values.get(i);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the value of the {@link #justifyFlag}. The column
         * values will be printed using String.format and
         * this flag will be used to right or left justify the text.
         *
         * @return The {@link #justifyFlag} of this column
         * @see #justifyLeft()
         */
        public String getJustifyFlag() {
            return justifyFlag;
        }

        /**
         * Sets {@link #justifyFlag} to "-" so that
         * the column value will be left justified when printed with
         * String.format. Typically numbers will be right
         * justified and text will be left justified.
         */
        public void justifyLeft() {
            this.justifyFlag = "-";
        }

        /**
         * Returns the generic SQL type category of the column
         *
         * @return The {@link #typeCategory} of the column
         */
        public int getTypeCategory() {
            return typeCategory;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the {@link #typeCategory} of the column
         *
         * @param typeCategory The type category
         */
        public void setTypeCategory(int typeCategory) {
            this.typeCategory = typeCategory;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the scala version of doing this... which will print column names and data as well in a generic way...

```
def printQuery(res: ResultSet): Unit = {
    val rsmd = res.getMetaData
    val columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount
    var rowCnt = 0
    val s = StringBuilder.newBuilder
    while (res.next()) {

      s.clear()
      if (rowCnt == 0) {
        s.append("| ")
        for (i <- 1 to columnCount) {
          val name = rsmd.getColumnName(i)
          s.append(name)
          s.append("| ")
        }
        s.append("\n")
      }
      rowCnt += 1
      s.append("| ")
      for (i <- 1 to columnCount) {
        if (i > 1)
          s.append(" | ")
        s.append(res.getString(i))
      }
      s.append(" |")
      System.out.println(s)
    }
    System.out.println(s"TOTAL: $rowCnt rows")
  }
```

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong in the Java class around line 100 it says "if (maxRows" and the line ends there EDIT: copy from the github link provided, not the answer above, the github class works

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TableSaw library](https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw), which is a great Java data science / data frame library. The code is simple then:

```
System.out.println(Table.read().db(resultSet).print());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). You made the following mistakes.
Firstly, `ps.executeQuery()` doesn't have any parameters. Instead you passed the SQL query into it.

Secondly, regarding the prepared statement, you have to use the `?` symbol if want to pass any parameters. And later bind it using

```
setXXX(index, value)
```

Here *xxx* stands for the data type.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, instead of `PreparedStatement` you can use `Statement`. Your code may be modified as-

```
String sql = "SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='suppliers';";

Statement s  = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with rowMapper impl.

Repository class:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sqlRequest, new ResponseQuikRowMapper())
```

Row mapper class:

```
public class ResponseQuikRowMapper implements RowMapper<Map<String, String>> {

@Override
@SneakyThrows
public Map<String, String> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
    return IntStream.range(1, rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount())
            .mapToObj(columnNumber -> getColumnName(rs, columnNumber))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(column -> column, value -> getColumnValue(rs, value)));
}

@SneakyThrows
private String getColumnName(ResultSet rs, Integer columnNumber) {
    return rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(columnNumber);
}

@SneakyThrows
private String getColumnValue(ResultSet rs, String column) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString(column)).orElse("");
}
```

HashMap it`s simple matrix where key is column name and value is value :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring data, you could try this:

```java
var mapped = new ColumnMapRowMapper().mapRow(resultSet, rowNum);
log.debug("Result={}", mapped);
```