# Resultset not returning values having special character /-,

Tags: java, jdbc

Some columns in my oracle db table has value which have special character.
Example Values:

> | 1 | Doe, John | 44/3 Demo-City | SomeCountry |

When i query the db from my java (jdbc) code i am getting empty string ("")  for column 2 and column 3 and there are no errors returned. Values for other two columns are comming correctly.

```
package pack;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Tester {
    
    static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain:1521:pid";
    static String user = "userid";
    static String pwd = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        String id = "1";    // I am receiving id value in method as parameter for reproducing purpose i am hardcoding it;
        
        String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID =" + id;
        
        String name = "";
        String address = ""; 
        String country = "";

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                
                name = rs.getString(2);
                address = rs.getString(3);
                country = rs.getString(4);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Name: "+name+"  Address:  "+address+"  Country:  "+country);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

The value returned for above:-

- id = 1;
- name = "";
- address = "";
- country = "SomeCountry";

Please suggest something to retrieve the values for the two missing columns.

Comment: Are you positive that there is no row where those columns are empty?

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I've never seen this specific kind of fault and I suspect that the reason lives somewhere slightly different than pure JDBC code. If you could reproduce this in a couple of lines of simple JDBC code, then that would help **a lot**.

Comment: @assylias yes I have verified this issue is not happening because of no data in db.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have update the code to reproduce. Please check.

Comment: @Shail: and running that code will reproduce the issue exactly? The first thing I'd try to do is replace the `SELECT *` with an explicit list of columns you return to verify we get what we expect. You've got some magic numbers in your `getString`  calls that seem suspicious. Also, can you try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229442/print-the-data-in-resultset-along-with-column-names) to verify which exact types and columns you get?

Comment: Are you sure the second column of `select *` is actually the name, and the third the address and the fourth the country?

Comment: @All Thanks everyone for looking into it. I have figured out the issue. The problem was occurring because of using incorrect version of the ojdbc jar. I had older version of of DB installed and was using the latest jar in local while writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case was because of using mismatch version of ojdbc jar and the db installed. The issue got resolved once I figured this out and used the correct version of the jar.